# stranger html content to normal html

Tags: php, html, xml, xhtml

I am writing a import function in PHP for importing news from a publisher. their API gives me newsml1.2 format response back, everything is fine but the body of a news looks as this

```
%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3B4+ya%C5%9F%C4%B1ndalar%2C+1+milyon+liradan+fazla+bor%C3%A7lar%C4%B1+var%26lt%3B%2Fp%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3B-
```

I have no idea what the format is that and I have tried with these functions but nothing change:

```
            $body = mysql_real_escape_string($body);
            iconv(mb_detect_encoding($body, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $body);
            htmlspecialchars($body, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $body = nl2br(html_entity_decode($body));
```

can somebody tell me what I should do. thanks

p.s.

I use the curl for getting the news list:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $HAS_USERNAME . ":" . $HAS_PASSWORD);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

than with simplexml

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($response);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `urldecode()` on the response:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response = '%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3B4+ya%C5%9F%C4%B1ndalar%2C+1+milyon+liradan+fazla+bor%C3%A7lar%C4%B1+var%26lt%3B%2Fp%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3B-';
$response = urldecode($response);
echo $response; // <p>4 yaşındalar, 1 milyon liradan fazla borçları var</p><p>-
```